# Mercurial, storing old changes for future use

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

In one of my Mercurial repos I have a main development branch that contains multiple commits that need to be removed and stored for (potential) future use. There have also been lots of other commits made since to the same branch that need to stay.

Using Mercurial (specifically 3.8 through TortoiseHG) is it possible to somehow store those changes in a separate branch, which would then allow me to remove them from the development branch?

The important thing is that the changes *might* be needed in the future (one of those customers!) so I want to be able to merge those changes back in.

I tried the following commits, but the removed changes were not re-implemented... and I can't figure out how to make them.

```
-1-2-3-4---6-7-8-9   <-- Development
        \     /
         5----       <-- Storage
```

- 1 - changes original made that I want to remove
- 2,3,4 - continuing development
- 5 - a new branch including the changes I want to remove
- 6 - removing the changes
- 7 - continuing development / releasing to customer
- 8 - merge the original changes back in
- 9 - continuing development

The problem is that the merge at #8 above does not re-implement the changes, as I believe the deletion at #6 overrides it.

Can anybody tell me an easy way to achieve it?

I've never fully got my head around Mercurial, so this might be a dead easy solution - but I can't see it.

Comment: Why remove them at all though? If the changes have been reverted as of 8 then they're effectively already removed, and they're being stored in both 1 and 5. If you need to reintroduce them later you could graft the changes in from 1 to where they need to be, or start development off of 5 and merge changes from the Development branch into the Storage branch.

Comment: *Why remove them at all though?* - a good question @Nanhydrin, and one I'm struggling to give a good answer for. The customer in question needed extensive integration code writing, but the system we needed integrate to was scrapped. It's possible in the future that they might bring in a new system so having the original code easily available (i.e. merging, not grafting) would be massively useful

Comment: Straight up removing them is going to be tough. You could maybe do it using mq, import everything up to and including 1 as a patch, pop them all, and then reapply one at a time editing as you go. However, that can be a nightmare, particularly if you've got a lot of XML filesto merge. You'd also have to get anyone else with a clone to delete all those revisions as well, so approach with caution. Another option would be to start a new branch at 10, make the changes and now you've got an isolated branch with the changes you want that can be merged later.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Nanhydrin

Comment: Can you not use `hg backout` after merging at 8? Or if you want to not remember which changeset to back out in some time in the future, can you merge 6 into your storage branch, then back it out? When you then merge storage into dev, 6 should be backed out.